# Why Qlik does not support the Protobuf schema while sending data to the Kafka topic from SQL Database table?

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, avro, qlikview, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to sending data from SQL Database Tables to Kafka topic directly using Qlik. I would like to generate protobuf schema while running the Qlik job for any specific topic. I didn't see any option to setup to generate protobuf schema for a Kafka topic. Is there any way we can setup Qlik to generate protobuf schema?

Basically it is creating AVRO schema for a topic and for the down stream I required Protobuf schema to runs any listener. I don't want any KSQL streams to convert from AVRO to Protobuf at this point to duplicate lots of data in the Kafka Cluster.

Thank you!!

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from using solutions like Debezium instead, which do support Protobuf? Also, KSQL supports Avro, too, so you don't need to duplicate anything. Use a pull query to get data out of KSQL without needing to deserialize anything

Comment: I don't remember properly but we had couple of issues while using the Debezium. That's  why we have started Qlik and now Qlik only supporting JSON and AVRO while our all down-stream is using protobuf and we don't want to add avro in our environment.

Comment: Okay, well, like I said, the KSQL REST-based client could be used to automatically deserialize the Avro into Row objects. That way, no Protobuf conversion is needed.

Comment: That's nice to know. Can you share any docs of it?

Comment: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-clients/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I would also like if Qlik can also support the protobuf then easy to solve this issue. Appreciate for your help.